# Show other input according to the radio buttons clicking?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have multiple radio input and i want when i click on a specific radio input ( with specific id ), the input button is shown 
and when i click on any of the other radio button the input disappear

```
    var radio = $("#radio7");
if($('#os_others').is(':hidden'))
{
    radio.click(function(){

        $('#os_others').slideDown();

    });

}
else
{
    $('#os_others').css("display", "none");
}
```

how can i achieve that ?

## Edit :

This is the demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/DgsM7/

when i click on others ... the input slide down , but what i want that when i click on other radio buttons the input box slide up

thanks

Comment: What's your ([representative/SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML, can we have a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Help *us* to help *you*, and you get better help and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#os_others").hide();

$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    //alert($("#radio7").is(":checked"));
    if ($("#radio7").is(":checked")) {
        $("#os_others").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#os_others").hide();
    }
});
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DgsM7/3/

Comment: i don't think you need the this.checked inside the slidetoggle.. http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: @tymeJV i want that when i click on other radio boxes the input slide up

Comment: @osos Please see the updated answer and fiddle, this should help.